# Prevent specific custom Gutenberg blocks from being used inside columns?

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, gutenberg-blocks

I have a custom Gutenberg block that utilizes Advanced Custom fields to display a full-width hero at the top of pages.

I'd like to find a way to prevent the user from using this block(acf/hero-block) inside columns(core/columns).

Is there a way I can remove this as an option only when attempting to used inside a column?

CSS seems like the most simple way but the box to select blocks isn't nested inside the actual columns.

[screenshot of popover box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cl1Sf.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: As far as I know, the only way to do this is to actually create the columns block yourself, and adding allowed blocks. That's the only true clean way I can think of doing this.

Comment: There is no current API to prevent a specific block from being inserted inside another block - there is an issue requesting this at https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/22592